# find(CTRL+F) in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I was searching for the some word which contains 2 bytes character in google spreadsheet. I used CTRL+F to find string in the cell.

Spreadsheet contains fallowing values.

```
Alianà
Aliana
```

I search the sheet with Aliana/Alianà I got 2 as search count.

I think it should return count as 1 for specific search.

Can any one help me to find why google spreadsheet work link this?

> For reference I am attaching [Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nd7_mjCVqWVewpIAQnb4m_ejX9fm9iE9YHvi6LzK52s/edit#gid=0)

Answer (score -1):

You can just specify to "Match case" in the advanced search panel.

[image: Example]

You can access it on the 3 dots at the right of the search input box when you Ctrl+F
[image]